# XSL numeric generate-id()

Tags: xml, xslt

How can XSL generate a unique id attribute for every element in an XML document using XSL where the id must be numeric? 
The XLS below works except that the generated ids are alphanumeric and I need numeric?

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>  
<xsl:stylesheet version='1.0' xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform'
    xmlns:msxsl='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt' exclude-result-prefixes='msxsl'>  
    <xsl:output method='xml' indent='yes'/>  
    <xsl:template match='*'>  
      <xsl:copy>  
        <xsl:attribute name='ElementID'>  
          <xsl:value-of select='generate-id()'/>  
        </xsl:attribute>  
        <xsl:apply-templates/>  
      </xsl:copy>  
    </xsl:template>    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Does it have to be XSLT 1.0? Can you update to 2.0?

Comment: Good Question (+1). See my answer for a more efficient and simpler solution. :)

Answer (score 7):

**You can always use**:

```
     concat(count(ancestor::node()),
           '00000000',
           count(preceding::node()))
```

**Knowledgeable people such as Michael Kay warn that `<xsl:number/>` is not efficient** (sometimes O(N^2)) and should be avoided if possible.

Comment: You have a misplaced bracket; the solution you likely wanted is `concat(count(ancestor::node()), '00000000', count(preceding::node()))`

Comment: @ToddMyhre: Thank you for noticing this. Corrected now.

Answer (score 3):

Switching using number() with level and count seems to have done the trick.

Thank you

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version='1.0' xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform'
    xmlns:msxsl='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt' exclude-result-prefixes='msxsl'>
    <xsl:output method='xml' indent='yes'/>
    <xsl:template match='*'>
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:attribute name='ElementID'>
          <xsl:number level='any' count='*' />
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/><!--copy of existing all attributes-->
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This is valid XSLT 1.0, no need for XSLT 2.0 in this case. Just as well, since in your code you've changed the version number for XML, not XSLT. ;-)

Comment: Well spotted Markusk, 2.0 removed

Comment: Added <xsl:copy-of > to preserve existing attributes

Comment: *Hint*: If this is a general algorithm, it may be a good idea to select a very special name for the attribute, in order to minimize the possibility of any element having an attribute with that name -- for example use something as `__________id`. :)